# listenbacklog directive not working in apache2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, connections

I was trying to make apache 2.2 reject connections if MaxClients was reached, to do this I found the directive ListenBacklog.To test it, I configured apache in the following way:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients            10
    ListenBacklog        1
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

I've made a little script in JMeter to test this. The test launchs 50 users in 1 second (it requests a phpinfo page) but none is rejected, they all wait!
I don't understand how this directive works...
my operating system is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/023/2333/2333s2.html -- Testing on LAN unlikely be precise.
2. Why do you think it should answer with TCP RST finally?
3. You can do this with Netfilter instead, but reasons are unclear; that behavior of the WEB-sever isn't user-friendly at all.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listenbacklog

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm implementing a little system that filters traffic to overloaded web servers, so it's desirable to tune the server in fail fast manner